# Debugging "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" for Flask App deployed on Apache with mod-wsgi-py3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: sqlite, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, cs50

I created a Flask app that uses Beautiful Soup and Selenium to scrape and track Amazon product prices. The data was stored using CS50's version of SQLalchemy.

I then created an account to use Oracle's always free VM, with Ubuntu. I followed this excellent guide to the dot https://asdkazmi.medium.com/deploying-flask-app-with-wsgi-and-apache-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-396607e0e40f and set up Apache's conf file and the Wsgi file. I also added the network rules on Oracle's Virtual Cloud Network and to iptables, which I believe works fine.

Following this, the website still couldn't launch. Apache's error log showed a "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/flask_session'". Based on this post [Permission issue when writing file on webserver (flask, apache & wsgi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357753/permission-issue-when-writing-file-on-webserver-flask-apache-wsgi) I changed the OS env to my env  `os.chdir('/home/ubuntu/flaskapp')` and used  chown to give rights
`sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data flaskapp`
`sudo chmod -R g+s flaskapp`.

Now, my front page is accessible on http://129.150.38.171/ . However, upon any request to the server, Chrome displays "This page isn’t working 129.150.38.171 didn’t send any data." Apache's log shows a "segmentation fault (core dumped) python flask".  Based on the sequence of my code, the error begins when I try to execute SQL, e.g. `rows = usersdb.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))`.

I do not think that it is not my codes' error as it runs fine locally and the production server also worked when I set it up on Oracle VM using this guide https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/flask-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-flask-summary.htm .

I've found this guide on debugging https://www.bustawin.com/debug-segmentation-faults-in-apache-from-mod_wsgi/ using gdb. But with `source /etc/apache2/envvars`
`sudo -E gdb /usr/sbin/apache`, it just tells me "No executable file specified".

Any ideas on what could be the error?

Comment: Are you facing error related to write permissions on disk?

Comment: I think you are right